# Routing issue No route matches post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, spree

I'm new to spree and having some issue with routes, on my form, when I click submit, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/admin/collection_pages/new"
```

I'm guessing POST is only for create method.

My Routes for the extension

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :collection_pages
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class CollectionPagesController < ResourceController
```

The form

```
    = semantic_form_for(:collecion_pages) do |f|
      = render :partial => 'spree/shared/error_messages', :locals => { :target => @collecion_pages }
.
.
.
      = submit_tag t("create")
```

any help would be greatly appreciated ! thank you so much

Comment: its all there spree/admin/collection_pages#index
                                                                        POST     /admin/collection_pages(.:format)                                                                                   spree/admin/collection_pages#create
                                              new_admin_collection_page GET      /admin/collection_pages/new(.:format)                                                                               spree/admin/collection_pages#new

Comment: Are you able to go to the index page with a link_to helper?  something like
    link_to spree.admin_collection_pages

Comment: since I was using ResourceController, create method is built in and couldn't add a redirect_to manually, this solved it: semantic_form_for(@collection_page, :url => admin_collection_pages_url